# Access to variabe in View class from main activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes, Main as main activity and DrawView (extends View) as a class where I have part of menu. I use class DrawView ONLY in main.xml file, what shows this menu part (kind of slider). In this DrawView is integer variable like 'currentSelection'.
How I can have access to this variable? I need later send this value to the second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `findViewById(R.id.give_the_custom_view_an_id)` in the main `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method and get a reference to your custom view and the access then variable.

Comment: Great! My first program, I forgot about it. Thanks a lot for quick answer, I couldn't even eat the dinner :D